# How to stop hibernate to do select before insert in child table in @ManyToOne mapping?

Tags: hibernate, spring-boot, jpa, spring-data-jpa, jpa-2.0

How to stop hibernate to do select before insert in child table in many to one mapping?

I have a student table :

```
    @Entity
    @Table
    @NoArgsConstructor
    @AllArgsConstructor
    @Builder
    @Data
    @IdClass(StudentId.class)

    public class Student implements Persistable<StudentId> {

        @Id
        private String studentUuid;

        @Id
        private String studentName;

        @Column
        private String sex;

        public Student(String studentUuid,String studentName){

            this.studentUuid = studentUuid;
            this.studentName = studentName;
        }

        @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
        @JoinColumns({
                @JoinColumn(
                        name = "classUuid",referencedColumnName = "classUuid"),
                @JoinColumn(
                        name = "className",referencedColumnName = "className")
        })
        private Class className;


        @Override
        public StudentId getId() {
            return new StudentId().builder().studentName(studentName).studentUuid(studentUuid).build();
        }

        @Override
        public boolean isNew() {
            return true;
        }
    }
```

I have a Class table:

```
@Entity
@Table
@Builder
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@Data
@IdClass(ClassId.class)
public class Class implements Persistable<ClassId> {


    @Id
    private String classUuid;

    @Id
    private String className;

    @Column
    private String classRoomNo;

    @Column
    private String classSize;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "className",cascade = CascadeType.ALL,fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    private List<Student> studentList;

    @Override
    public ClassId getId() {
        return new ClassId().builder().className(className).classUuid(classUuid).build();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isNew() {
        return true;
    }
}
```

Whenever i do studentRepo.save(studentEntity) it always do select from parent class i.e. Class table then if the data exists in the parent table then it do insert in child table i.e. student.
Cannot it happen in a single network call rather then hitting two calls first select from parent then insert.

Comment: Do you think it is related with the Cascade in the Class @ManyToOne mapping?

Comment: I apologize if this sounds combative, but if you're going to worry about micromanaging SQL at that level across your entire project, walk away from hibernate now :) :)  (especially if you're set on using those weird composite string keys and not a surrogate ID number.....)

Comment: I'm a fan of understanding what your database is doing and not a fan of multiple sql statements when they are not necessary but I have to agree with @Affe that your code and Ids are very unusual and not standard and you should understand the basic before you try to fix the subtle stuff. If you don't want the select before insert then don't use cascades and develop a better understanding of owning entities and performance considerations.

Comment: Hi Affe and @K.Nicholas can you help me in understanding what is wrong and this is not the actual code this is just a pseudo where i am trying to understand how to stop select query before insert in hibernate.Since in db if i try to save in the child table and the foreign key doesn't match in the parent table then it will throw constraint violation exception rather then first hit select query in the parent table.

Comment: @Brother nope.I have tried with removing those but still it hits select query.

Comment: @Affe the main problem of using surrogate key is that we are going to provide public api to the user so every time they will hit those save api it will create a new entry which we dont want.

Comment: *The main problem of using surrogate key is that we are going to provide public api to the user so every time they will hit those save api it will create a new entry which we dont want.* Sorry, but this is nonsense. You are are trying to optimise before you even understand the basics. Learn the basics of JPA, get persistence working and then look at optimising.

Comment: @Alan pretty new to jpa/hibernate/oracle. Regarding surrogate key say for an ex: if in my Class Entity there is a surrogate key classId which is an auto-generated uuid. Every time anyone calls an ClassApi to save the data then in the backend it will call classRepo.save(ClassEntity) and since we are using surrogate key then there is a chance of data duplication since it will always be unique.Thats why we are using composite key which are not auto generated so that in the hibernate layer it will do update rather then insert since the row already exist.Please clarify me if i am wrong.

Comment: The simple answer is historically in relational databases querying on primary IDs is cheap and rollbacks are very very very expensive.  The designers of hibernate decided that a 'defensive' select is better than an intentional rollback when the system is configured the way you did it.  I would broadly agree that a design that intentionally causes ConstraintViolationException to detect *expected business states* or *valid operations* is a flawed design.  The problems you will eventually face by using primary keys to enforce business rules are the exact reason everyone says use a surrogate ID ;)

Comment: My main point is just Hibernate is a highly opinionated framework and really wants to do things "its way."  Fighting against it is going to lead you to a very frustrating experience.  There are several ways your project could be reorganized to prevent that select, but honestly one would need to analyze the whole project and refactor it.  Any one way we might suggest could easily make other things worse.  There are plenty of good SO answers on *why* it's doing the select in the first place that could probably help you find a good path forward.

Comment: God only knows what is going on because because you didn't show the code. If you want to know what is wrong with your code then show it. Last time I tried saving a child without having saved the parent I got an error, so who knows what you are doing.

Comment: K.Nicholas i will also get an error but the point is how the error comes.In hibernate layer error comes in a way where it first do select query in the parent table and if it doesn't get any data then it throws error.

Comment: @Affe thanks for your comment and yea you do make sense. I will be doing a better model design.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, you want to save or use existing class (if exists) within the same call. The performance-best way to do this is to insert and handle exception in case of failure. However, the best practice is to make separate requests to the database: first, to check if the class exists; second, to insert it (if needed), and then insert a student. My advice to you would be to create a separate `@Transactional` service method, that would execute that operation for you. Just like this:

```
private final ClassRepository classRepository;

@Transactional
public Student createStudent(Object studentDto) {

    Class cls = classRepository.findByClassUuid(studentDto.getStudentClass().getClassUuid())
            // in case it returns optional
            .orElse(classRepository.save(Class.builder()
                    .className("..")
                    .classSize("..")
                    //...
            .build()));

    Student studentEntity = new Student();
    // setters skipped
    return studentRepo.save(studentEntity);
}
```

Just make sure you add the package name to your `class` class, otherwise, compiler will think of java.lang.Class.

Comment: @llya thanks for the quick response but my main problem is why we need to hit select query and do two seperate network call when oracle/sql can handle this kind of use cases with constraint.