# How to stop inserting in Parent table if the foreign key exists in child table composite key in jpa in @ManyToOne bidirectional?

Tags: hibernate, spring-boot, jpa, spring-data-jpa, jpa-2.0

I have two table:
  One is Class Table that is the parent table and another is student table that is the child table in @OneToMany bidirectional mapping:

```
@Entity
@Table
@Builder
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@Data
@IdClass(ClassId.class)
public class Class implements Persistable<ClassId> {


    @Id
    private String className;

    @Id
    private String classId;


    @Column
    private String classContent;

    @JsonIgnore
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "class_fk",cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    private List<Student> studentList;


    @Override
    public ClassId getId() {

        return new classId//using builder
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isNew() {
        return true;
    }
}
```

Another one is student Table :

```
@Entity
@Table
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@Builder
@Data
@IdClass(StudetnId.class)
public class Student implements Persistable<StudetnId> {

    @Id
    @Column
    private String studentName;

    @Id
    @Column
    private String studentGroup;

    @Id
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumns ({
            @JoinColumn(
                    name = "className",referencedColumnName = "className"),
            @JoinColumn(
                    name = "classId",referencedColumnName = "classId")
    })
    private Class class_fk;


    @Column
    private String displayName;

    @Column
    private String active;

    @Override
    public StudentId getId() {
        return new StudentId//using builder
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isNew() {
        return true;
    }
}
```

And the student Id class is a composite key which contains class, studentName and studentGroup where the data inside the class i.e. className and classId are the foreign key as well as the primary key.

```
@Builder
@Data
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
public class StudentId implements Serializable {

    private Class class;
    private String studentName;
    private String studentGroup;
}
```

The problem is whenever I do studentRepo.save(studentEntity) it inserts data in both the table i.e. class table as well as student table.

The requirement is if we do insert in student table whose foreign key i.e. class name and class Id doesn't exist in the Class table then hibernate should throw an error instead of inserting in both the table.

```
Class classOne = Class.builder().className("Sec-B").classID("111").build();
Student student = Student.builder().studentName("Niladri").studentGroup("Science").class_fk(classOne).displayName("ScienceBackground").active("true").build().
studentRepo.save(student);
```

It first insert into class and then insert into student.

Comment: You need to add the code where you construct and save this entity.

Comment: Why have you overridden `isNew()`? Don't you think that might have something to do with your issue??

Comment: @Alan Hay isNew by true it will always do insert rather then fetch and then insert.

Comment: @Alan i have added the part of the code where i construct and save the entity.

Comment: If you want to associate a student with an existing class then you get a reference to that entity and use that: don't construct a new instance with the same ID. And the remove the pointless `isNew()` overrides.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because:

The user has already asked the same question a number of hours before and this existing question has already received comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56756965/how-to-stop-hibernate-to-do-select-before-insert-in-child-table-in-manytoone-ma

Comment: @AlanHay If you go through the question clearly you will see the difference both entity model are different. In this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56756965/how-to-stop-hibernate-to-do-select-before-insert-in-child-table-in-manytoone-ma i have asked why hibernate does select query everytime before it inserts and in this question i have asked why does hibernate do insert into parent entity and then into child entity and i have also given the use case i want.

Comment: @Alan Hay regarding isNew() you can go through this link once.  https://dzone.com/articles/persisting-natural-key-entities-with-spring-data-j